# Translate and Scale animation in parallel

Tags: android, parallel-processing, scale, translate-animation

I want to move some view from any position to **center** of screen and scale in parallel. If that's too complicated, **translate** and **scale** sequentially is also acceptable. But neither I could achieve. I think it's the problem with the pivot point. But sorry I found no solution. Please help. Maybe it's easy to those who develop games, about which I did nothing.

Below is my code:

```
private void moveViewToScreenCenter( final View view ){
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
    int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - rootLayout.getMeasuredHeight();

    int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

    int xDelta = (dm.widthPixels - view.getMeasuredWidth())/2 - originalPos[0];
    int yDelta = (dm.heightPixels - view.getMeasuredHeight())/2 + statusBarOffset - originalPos[1];

    AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animSet.setFillAfter(true);
    animSet.setDuration(1000);
    animSet.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDelta , 0, yDelta);
    animSet.addAnimation(translate);
    ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 2f, 1f, 2f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, .5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, .5f);
    animSet.addAnimation(scale);
    view.startAnimation(animSet);
}
```

**Update:**
code above can handle imageview from top left region, those from bottom right region go diagonally through the screen and disappear.

Answer (score 24):

After quite a few hopeless trials, I made it, which is too astonishing.

Below is the code, it can be used to move any view in a layout to the center of that layout:

```
private void moveViewToScreenCenter( final View view ){
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );

    int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

    int xDelta = (dm.widthPixels - view.getMeasuredWidth() - originalPos[0])/2;
    int yDelta = (dm.heightPixels - view.getMeasuredHeight() - originalPos[1])/2;

    AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animSet.setFillAfter(true);
    animSet.setDuration(1000);
    animSet.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDelta , 0, yDelta);
    animSet.addAnimation(translate);
    ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 2f, 1f, 2f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, .5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, .5f);
    animSet.addAnimation(scale);
    view.startAnimation(animSet);
}
```

Comment: Your `animSet.setFillAfter(true);` saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

The core idea is:

```
AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

animationSet.addAnimation(
  new TranslateAnimation(0f, 64f, 0f, 32f),
  new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0f, 1f, 0f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f););

myView.startAnimation(
  animationSet);
```